# Permission denied in Docker build

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have following docker file

```
FROM something.com/..../lrh7:latest
RUN whoami
SHELL ["/usr/sbin", "-c"]
RUN /usr/sbin/groupadd -g 1000 AB_DOCKER_SETUP_GROUP
```

when I do a docker build then it fails stating permission denied

```
container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"/usr/sbin\": permission denied"
```

but when I change

```
RUN /usr/sbin/groupadd -g 1000 AB_DOCKER_SETUP_GROUP
```

to

```
CMD ["su", "-" ,"groupadd", "-g", "1000", "AB_DOCKER_SETUP_GRO"]
```

then docker build succeed. Output of whoami is ROOT which means I am running as root, even after that I have to specify sudo explicitly to add group.

Running

```
RUN su - /usr/sbin/groupadd -g 1000 AB_DOCKER_SETUP_GROUP # sudo/su both fails
```

also fails with permission denied. I have no clarity whats happening behind the scene.

Answer (score 21):

For me, it was the issue with the missing permission for the Docker

I fixed the issue with the following command.

```
sudo chmod -R g+rw "$HOME/.docker"
```

FYI: I am using a Mac M1 machine.

Comment: This helped me with the issue with my mac setup.

Comment: This did not help solve the same problem under Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Hey @CPBL there might be some other command to try for Ubuntu. As I mentioned i tried it on my mac and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

What the SHELL command does is setting the default shell in your container for the shell mode executions. You are setting it wrong in your script. The subsequent RUN command is done in the shell mode and it triggers the problem with the wrong default shell you have specified.

Also, you should refer to your shell through symbolic link than trying to specify it in the `sbin` system directory. The `/bin/sh -c` is the default shell for linux - so, you don't have to set it explicitly.

The reason why your `CMD []` work is that it is executed in the command mode - so, the it doesn't try to use the wrong default shell you have specified.

The following script is enough in your use case:

```
FROM something.com/..../lrh7:latest
RUN whoami
RUN groupadd -g 1000 AB_DOCKER_SETUP_GROUP
```

OR, if you still DO want to specify the same default shell:

```
FROM something.com/..../lrh7:latest
RUN whoami
SHELL ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
RUN groupadd -g 1000 AB_DOCKER_SETUP_GROUP
```

Another way of running your command is as an executable. This helps when you don't have a shell in your image.

```
RUN ["groupadd", "-g", "1000", "AB_DOCKER_SETUP_GROUP"]
```

Comment: when I run your dockerfile, I get /bin/sh: groupadd: command not found error

Comment: What are you pulling your image from? Can you post your actual docker file?

Comment: this is custom in house image, I too doubt something fishy with this image. Only from URL is changed otherwise that's actual file

Comment: What did you try - my first snippet or the second one?

Comment: Both are the same by action. The /bin/sh should be available in linux images. It is there in the smallest image.

Comment: Try running bash on your image RUN /bin/bash -c. Then connect to the running container and see why the shell is not available.

Comment: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"groupadd\": executable file not found in $PATH"
oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"groupadd\": executable file not found in $PATH"

Comment: Find where the executable is and direct it Also, find why your image don't have any shell.

Comment: It did not work for me

Answer (score 1):

*Surprisingly had the same problem.*

1. Change the ownership of docker.socket

   sudo chown root:docker /var/run/docker.sock
2. Type the following command to ensure that you own the hidden .docker directory located in your home directory. The -R option applies the command recursively to all the subdirectories.

   sudo chown -R "$USER":"$USER" $HOME/.docker
3. Assign group read and write permissions with the chmod command.

   sudo chmod -R g+rw "$HOME/.docker"

Answer (score -1):

run your command with sudo like sudo docker build -t server:v1 .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).